I'm having a terrible texture glitch with pygame + python in my little doom renderer clone
For whatever reason, on certain walls, but not all of them, the texture is bugged and looks repeated, like color bars? Almost like the texture is repeating over and over again? I'm so confused, and I've been trying to debug it for hours and nothing is working. It's not like other questions (it was removed) because I've already looked over them and nothing works. Please help. Thank you for your time, kind stangers.
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
FPS = 60
MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT = 10, 10
TILE_SIZE = 64

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

game_map = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
]

wall_texture = pygame.image.load('wall_texture.png')
wall_texture = pygame.transform.scale(wall_texture, (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))

player_pos = [1.5, 1.5]
player_angle = 0
player_speed = 0.05
rotation_speed = 0.03

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("ARCHIIV")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def cast_ray(angle):
    sin_a = math.sin(angle)
    cos_a = math.cos(angle)
    ray_length = 0
    hit = False
    intersect_x, intersect_y = 0, 0

    while not hit and ray_length < 20:
        ray_length += 0.04
        test_x = player_pos[0] + cos_a * ray_length
        test_y = player_pos[1] + sin_a * ray_length
        map_x = int(test_x)
        map_y = int(test_y)

        if 0 <= map_x < MAP_WIDTH and 0 <= map_y < MAP_HEIGHT and game_map[map_y][map_x] == 1:
            hit = True
            intersect_x, intersect_y = test_x, test_y

    return ray_length, intersect_x, intersect_y, map_x, map_y

def render():
    ray_angles = [player_angle - math.pi / 6 + (x / WIDTH) * (math.pi / 3) for x in range(WIDTH)]
    
    for x, ray_angle in enumerate(ray_angles):
        ray_length, intersect_x, intersect_y, map_x, map_y = cast_ray(ray_angle)

        corrected_ray_length = ray_length * math.cos(player_angle - ray_angle)
        wall_height = HEIGHT / (corrected_ray_length + 0.0001)
        wall_top = (HEIGHT // 2) - (wall_height // 2)
        wall_bottom = (HEIGHT // 2) + (wall_height // 2)

        if abs(intersect_x - map_x) > abs(intersect_y - map_y): 
            texture_x = (intersect_y % 1) * TILE_SIZE 
        else: 
            texture_x = (intersect_x % 1) * TILE_SIZE 

        texture_rect = pygame.Rect(texture_x, 0, 1, TILE_SIZE)
        wall_slice = wall_texture.subsurface(texture_rect)
        wall_slice = pygame.transform.scale(wall_slice, (1, int(wall_height)))

        screen.blit(wall_slice, (x, int(wall_top)))

def move_player(dx, dy):
    new_x = player_pos[0] + dx
    new_y = player_pos[1] + dy
    if game_map[int(new_y)][int(new_x)] == 0:
        player_pos[0] = new_x
        player_pos[1] = new_y

def main():
    global player_angle
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            move_player(math.cos(player_angle) * player_speed, math.sin(player_angle) * player_speed)
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            move_player(-math.cos(player_angle) * player_speed, -math.sin(player_angle) * player_speed)
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            move_player(-math.sin(player_angle) * player_speed, math.cos(player_angle) * player_speed)
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            move_player(math.sin(player_angle) * player_speed, -math.cos(player_angle) * player_speed)
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player_angle -= rotation_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player_angle += rotation_speed

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        render()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

